# iOS URL Scheme for OWA, Office 365 Business

Tags: uri

Do you guys know the URL Scheme for OWA?

For example, outlook has `ms-outlook://`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: Those are for excel, word, etc, not for OWA.