# Deep Linking for opening Outlook Groups app from another app

Tags: android, ios, outlook, office365, deep-linking

We're building an app that display data from Outlook Groups. Is there any schema or URL support for opening a group from another app?

Does anyone know if there is any support for URL Schemes for this?

The Outlook app can open a new email with: `ms-outlook://compose`.

Microsoft have this documentation that seems outdated: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx which is also linked in this question [iOS URL Scheme for OWA, Office 365 Business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418839/ios-url-scheme-for-owa-office-365-business).

Opening a url from O365 in browser on iOS shows a page with info about downloading the app and the badge that there is an app available to there seems to be some support.

Maybe if I would use the same URI as the "Open" badge calls - but how can I find out?

[image: URL]

Update:

I've requested this at UserVoice as well https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293349-outlook-for-ios/suggestions/32449574-enable-deep-linking-support-for-groups-in-outlook

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use explicit intent for opening  different app from your app by using this code 

Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name of application");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you but I wan't to do the opposite; Open the Microsoft apps from my app.

So Microsoft need to implement this.

Comment: Hello . This code is implemented when you want user to open your app from anywhere in phone we he taps a particular url scheme .
User will get your app and all other different apps to open that

Comment: I don't want to open my app. The users are in my app showing content from Microsoft systems such as SharePoint etc. I want to open the SharePoint, Yammer or Outlook app from my app.

Comment: Yes but I still can't open a specific item. Just launch the app. LinkedIn app for instance will open your profile - not main page of app, right?

Comment: You have to put package name and put data in intent which you want to send and that app will handle it